# In how many ways can k vertices be partitioned into k/2 pairs?

Tags: graph-theory

This is supposed to be a really trivial answer I think, but I guess I'm missing something, because it confuses me a lot.

Suppose G has k vertices of odd degree. In how many ways can the odd vertices be partitioned into k/2 pairs?

My first guess was something like 2^k, but I'm thinking now it's some factorial type function, like n choose k.

Comment: How many ways can you pick half of the vertices?

Comment: Vertices...can't be partitioned into parts. Graphs can.

Comment: To clarify: $k/2$ parts means you have $k/2$ buckets in which you place $k$ objects?

Comment: Sorry, that should say "k/2 pairs", not parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $k$ must be even; say $k=2m$, so that you’re counting the ways to divide the set of odd vertices into $m$ parts. If there is no restriction on the sizes of the individual parts, this is ${2m}\brace m$, a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind); the sequence of these ‘central’ Stirling numbers is [OEIS A$007820$](http://oeis.org/A007820); at the link you’ll find the (rather ugly) explicit formula

$${{2m}\brace m}=\frac1{m!}\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k(m-k)^{2m}$$

and a few other odds and ends.

**Added to match the revised question:** Since the parts are all pairs, a much nicer explicit formula is available. There are $$\binom{2m}{\underbrace{2,2,\ldots,2}_m}=\frac{(2m)!}{2^m}$$ ways to choose an $m$-tuple of pairs of vertices, so there are $$\frac{(2m)!}{2^mm!}=(2m-1)!!$$ ways to choose an unordered set of $m$ pairs of vertices.

Comment: Sorry, my original post was flawed writing. There is restriction on the size of the parts; it's 2. My question has been edited accordingly.

Comment: @humdiddlediddle: I’ve added an answer to the intended question.